# Server requires signed URL (Unity Ads API)

Tags: ios, http, url, unity-game-engine

I want to fetch my statistics for Unity Ads in an iOS application. Unity provides an API for this, however they state that

> "The statistics server always requires signed URLs and will not work
>   if accessed without a valid signature."

What is a signed URL and how should I access the server? A normal NSURLRequest does not work and I get the error message:
`{"error":"Authentication error","responseCode":500,"status":"error"}`

Here is the code I am using(making a request this way works for other apis, just not with unity ads)

```
- (IBAction)Button:(id)sender {
    // Create the request.
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gameads-admin.applifier.com/stats/acquisition-api?apikey=979c4e733ccd85a1eaef74e28f9dc1742d5fa5a2b3518fe10825aa13caf18185"]];

    // Create url connection and fire request
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sending your api key as a GET parameter in your request?

`api?apikey=APIKEY`

[image: API]

---

https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/Documentation%20for%20Publishers/Statistics-API-for-monetisation

> In order to use the Unity Ads Statistics API, you need to get the **API key** from the Unity Ads Admin Panel. The API key is located in the Account Settings page.
>
> The API key needs to be placed in the authentication request to the apikey HTTP GET parameter.
>
> For example curl -L "http://gameads-admin.applifier.com/stats/acquisition-api?apikey=APIKEY" will directly output the file to the console.

---

UPDATE

There seems to be something wrong with your setup if you provided the correct API KEY (Which you should not post here by the way). I executed your example in the terminal.

> ➜ ~ curl -L "http://gameads-admin.applifier.com/stats/acquisition-api?apikey=YOUR_API_KEY"
>   {"error":"Authentication error","responseCode":500,"status":"error"}%

Then I ran one of our games and got a different result

> ➜ ~ curl -L "http://gameads-admin.applifier.com/stats/acquisition-api?apikey=OUR_HIDDEN_API_KEY"
>   Date,Country code,Country tier,started,views,clicks,installs,spend

Comment: Yes!  I have copied my own api key and pasted it into the example they provided at the bottom of the page and still get the same error

Comment: Yes sure! The problem is with the request so I only post that part(updated my question).

Comment: Just to be sure. The app is setup correctly and working in Unity right?

Comment: Yes of course! I can see my revenue and video starts in the  Unity Admin Panel, I just want to be able to easily access these statistics from my iphone so I though I would write a quick iOS app for this purpose

Comment: Good. I updated my answer. Using curl in the terminal with our API KEYS works. If I use yours I get the 500 result.